# Stack on commutative ring spectra?

Tags: homotopy-theory, algebraic-stacks

One approach to stacks to call a stack a "sheaf of groupoids" which means a functor 
$$ \mathcal{C}^{\text{op}} \rightarrow \mathcal{G} $$
from a category $\mathcal{C}$ with a Grothendieck topology to the category of (small) groupoids $\mathcal{G}$ ([small] 1-groupoids) satisfying a descent condition.

The usual way of doing this is with $\mathcal{C}:$=$R$-mod, for a commutative ring $R$, with the flat topology, but certainly other choices could be made. I have recently heard that there is a well defined notion of $\text{spec}(E)$ for $E$ a commutative ring spectrum.

Question 1: Is there such a thing as a stack on commutative ring spectra?

Question 2: Can equivariant structure be encoded into the geometry in some way so that this perspective gives you new new tools to work with equivariant homotopy?

Question 3: Are there other uses for this construction in the literature?

Comment: "Stack of $X$es" means that the category of $X$es is the target category, not the source category (and so in this sense people do in fact study stacks of ring spectra, e.g. when constructing elliptic cohomology, although usually they'll call them sheaves of ring spectra). You want "stack on..." instead.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Do you have a preferred reference for  elliptic cohomology?

Comment: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/survey.pdf is quite nice.

Comment: It seems that the answer to the first question can be yes formally by letting $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of commutative ring spectra. Andrew Salch told me this when I asked him the question in person. I reformatted my last thought into a second question since this one way I thought a stack on commutative ring spectra could be useful.